# Can I rename a portion of code released under Apache 2.0?

Tags: licensing, apache-license

Is it possible to rename a portion of code extracted from a Apache 2.0 licensed software, releasing it as a new repository under a new name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly.

As all open-source licenses, Apache license allows publishing derived work. Some allow using different license too (Apache license does), some don't (GPL).